# How does the ICC enforce its judgements?

Tags: human-rights, international-criminal-court

I was wondering: how does the International Criminal Court (ICC) enforce its judgements?

It has no military power whatsoever, so it seems to me they can only rely on the country where the crime is happening. But what if it is a high-ranking official? How does the ICC deal with that?

Comment: For clarity, i presume that you are referring to the "International Criminal Court" which enforces war crime type violations and similar crimes against humanity, and not, for example, the Interstate Commerce Commission. It is better practice to spell out all abbreviations at least once as all acronyms have multiple meanings.

Comment: See also the International Commercial Court (ICC). https://lsolum.typepad.com/legaltheory/2021/04/rogers-on-the-legitimacy-ethics-of-international-commercial-court-judges.html

Answer (score 8):

[Rome Statute, Article 103](http://www.preventgenocide.org/law/icc/statute/part-c.htm):

> Article 103: **Role of States in enforcement of sentences of imprisonment**
>
> 1. (a) A sentence of imprisonment **shall be served in a State designated by the Court** from a list of States which have indicated to the Court their willingness to accept sentenced persons.

So, this looks pretty straightforward: certain States declare their willingness to serve the orders of ICC, and States obviously have military power to enforce that.

---

Update, responding to peer pressure regarding high-ranking officials.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Criminal_Court_investigations) contains an exhaustive list of all ICC investigations and trials.

One may notice that **all** cases so far were against high-ranking officials.

Also, all arrests so far are done in custody of respective State's authorities. This happened, for example, with Libyan *Saif al-Islam Gaddafi* who has been arrested only after *Muammar Gaddafi* died.

Comment: The answer doesn't mention actual situations where this has occurred with high-ranking officials (or if such examples exist).

Comment: @PointlessSpike you're right. I assumed a conscientious user would check Wikipedia first, but anyway let me add it to the answer.